# Teradata C++ UDF

Tags: teradata

I tried to create a function using object file and by using the following set of queries

```
REPLACE FUNCTION db_1.append(inputString VARCHAR(512))
RETURNS VARCHAR(512)
LANGUAGE CPP
NO SQL
EXTERNAL NAME 'CO!tokenise!/root/Desktop/tokenise.o!F!append'
PARAMETER STYLE TD_GENERAL;
```

I had built gcc from source and created a soft link of gcc executable and g++ to the /usr/bin directory.After inserting the object file I got the following error inside teradata.

*** Failure 5600 Error creating UDF/XSP/UDM/UDT: no compiler available.
                Statement# 1, Info =0